# Interactive map, which unlocks if you provide email. What is the best way to get started on this?

Tags: email, dictionary, location, interactive

So basically there is to be a map, and users are able to drop a pin in to note their location. To access the map and pin, an email must be provided.

So like you go to the site, there is a prompt for your email to proceed then that window closes after an email is given and there is a map and a pin that you can drop where ever you want.

What is the best way to do this?

I am finding interactive map tutorials that lead to external pages, or pop up windows for facts but nothing as visceral as putting a pin in a location with your name on it.

Also while we want to get the email, we want it in NO WAY to be connected to the pin information wise.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, how you want to achieve it, what you have tried and if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

So I will make a guess and say you wan't this for a website, (should state what language or system you are doing this for) 
Just have a simple
[Javascript pop up with a text field](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input).
Or  [use googles API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)